# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::skip does not exist - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, collections, pagination, skip

I'm using laravel 5.8

I have this closed query:

> $user = User::get();

and Then this doesn't work:

> $user->skip(20)->take(10);

This occurs:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::skip does not exist.

Tell me what should I do to achieve this without error?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly

Comment: @Abiola Trying to paginate a closed query.

Answer (score 3):

**Tl;dr** For 5.8, the solution is to use `slice();` So it becomes to `$user->slice(20)->take(10);`

If you wonder why `$users = User::skip(20)->take(10)->get();` works, but the code below is not working.

```php
$user = User::get();
$user->skip(20)->take(10);
```

This is because, when you use `Eloquent` to query database many chainable methods (like: `where`, `skip` and many others) will translate to query builder, but when you call `get` it's going to return the whole result from database to your local memory, so it becomes to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`inherents from `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

For 5.8 the `Collection` does not have `skip` method. So you get that error.

It's added since 6, so you in order to achieve what you want you either update to 6 + or use `slice()`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but this should work

```
$users = User::skip(20)->take(10)->get();
```

This also works

```
$users = DB::table('users')->skip(20)->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Bro, I want do this after closing my query.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by 'paginate a closed query'

Comment: Normally if you're trying to paginate you'll do something like this `User::all()->paginate(10);` Are you trying to add some special condition?